# Is it possilbe to rename a job in AWS Glue?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

As in the title of my post, it is possible? I don't see any options.
Also, the job details include **advanced properties** that include the name of my script, for example, **job-name.py** When the python script is renamed, will the job name also change? I'm afraid I might mess something up after the change.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From CloudFormation docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) is stated that changing the name parameter would replace the job so I would say no.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @zoran2709:

> From CloudFormation docs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-job.html) is stated that changing the name parameter would replace the job so I would say no.

In the console, it doesn't look like you can. If you defined this job in CloudFormation, you can update the name of the job, but it will replace the resource with a new one. I would recommend setting the `UpdateReplacePolicy` on the resource to `Retain` just to be safe. Checkout the docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatereplacepolicy.html):

> If you update a resource property that requires that the resource be replaced, CloudFormation recreates the resource during the update. Recreating the resource generates a new physical ID. CloudFormation creates the replacement resource first, and then changes references from other dependent resources to point to the replacement resource. By default, CloudFormation then deletes the old resource. Using the UpdateReplacePolicy, you can specify that CloudFormation retain or, in some cases, create a snapshot of the old resource.